# CW approximation is unique - question about proof

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

I am reading the section about CW approximations in Hatcher's algebraic topology (the 2015 reprint), and I am having trouble with understanding the proof of uniqueness for CW approximation (up to homotopy equivalence). His argument goes as follows:

If $f:Z\rightarrow X, g:Z'\rightarrow X$ are both CW approximations for $X$, we can look at the composition $Z\stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} X \hookrightarrow M_g$, where $M_g$  is the mapping cylinder of $g$ and from what I understand the second map is the inclusion of $X$ into the mapping cylinder.

He then claims that by the compression lemma, the composition above can be deformed into $Z'$ which gives a weak homotopy equivalence between $Z$ and $Z'$ (and hence a homotopy equivalence, due to Whitehead's theorem).

I am not sure about two things:

1. How is the compression lemma applied? I understand that we consider $Z'$ as a subspace of the mapping cylinder, but I do not understand what subspace of $Z$ we are considering in the domain and why the conditions for the lemma are met.
2. Why does the composition give a weak homotopy equivalence? The induced map of homotopy groups is certainly injective as the composition of injections. But why is is surjective? The first arrow is surjective, and the second arrow is probably surjective somehow due to how we use the compression lemma, but I do not understand why (which relates to my first question).

Can somebody please explain this to me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question 2 seems strange: Why are you concerned about injectivity and surjectivity of those maps? Did you perhaps intend to ask instead about injectivity and surjectivity of certain induced homomorphisms?

Comment: @LeeMosher Yes, of course. I rephrased it.

Comment: Hatcher explains #1 in the proof of Prop 4.18 (p. 355). Where are your questions for his proof? For #2, once you have 4.18, as Hatcher says in 4.19, you get maps $Z \to Z' \to Z$. This composition is homotopic to the identity map on $Z$ by 4.18.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri In the edition I am working with, these proposition and corollary come only after the proof I am referring to, which is on page 352. Do you think that there is a more elementary way to understand what he wrote, without first going over the more general statements you wrote, which come several pages after?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Also, 4.18 does not really seem to completely answer question no. 1, since the details I asked about are still missing

Comment: I do not consider the paragraph on p. 352 a proof, but rather an outline of the argument that is made more precise a few pages later in 4.18. The proof of 4.18 explains why the relevant homotopy groups are zero. The whole thing is given for a pair $(X,A)$, and $A$ is the subspace of $Z$. If you want to consider the absolute case (just starting with $X$ rather than $(X,A)$), then let $A$ be a point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have thought about this, and this is the explanation I came up with:

The compression lemma is applied to the pairs $(Z,z_0)\rightarrow (M_f,Z')$.

Since $Z'$ is a deformation retract of $M_f$, the conditions for the compression lemma are met automatically.

The second induced map in the homotopy groups (the right arrow) is surjective since in this particular case, it is easy to see (via, say, the long exact sequence of homotopy groups) that $\pi_n(M_f,X)=0$ for all $n$, and so the inclusion induces an isomorphism.

Comment: $Z'$ is not a defomation retract of $M_f$. It is not even a subset of $M_f$.