# Homotopy Long Exact Sequence Coming From the Mapping Cylinder

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

Hatcher defines the mapping cylinder $M_f$ of a map $f : Z\to X$ as the quotient space of the disjoint union of $Z\times I$ and $X$ under the identifications $(z, 1) \sim f (z)$.

My question is that if we have a map $X\hookrightarrow M_f$, how can we use the long exact sequence of homotopy groups to show that $\pi_n(M_f, X) = 0$ for all $n$? What would the long exact sequence look like in this case?

Also, how can we see that $Z$ is a deformation retract of $M_f$?

I'm referring to the answer posted on this question:
[CW approximation is unique - question about proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4205997/cw-approximation-is-unique-question-about-proof)

Comment: $X$ is a deformation retract of $M_f$. Put $h(x,t)=x$ and $h(z,s,t) = (z,(1-t)s+t)$ to define a deformation retraction. But $Z$ is not a deformation retract.

Comment: @VincentBoelens Why noit an official answer?